# iOS - How to use inheritance in custom cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I have 6 custom cells in tablview. All custom cell has 2 types data. First is label. And 2nd is different from each one. So, I want to use here inheritance. like this : 
Base custom cell class contains :  label 1 ,and label 2.
child custom cell class contains : label 1, label 2 and other components which are different from each other custom cell.

So, in short, I want to make labels in custom cell **or without** custom cell and inherit in all (6) custom cell. But I don't know how to do it. Any suggestion will be great . Thank in advance .

Comment: Ref: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ .Or: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Comment: Thanks @ Anthu . But I want to make custom cell **with inheritance.** You have given me simple custom cell example without inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you created your cell (in interface builder or not) this should be easy. I would recommend creating your cell in code, and then inherit the cell (usually you would use UITableViewCell now create your base cell class and inherit new cells from your new custom cell i.e. MyCustomBaseTableViewCell).

Comment: Thanks @ Tafh . I have created custom cell in interface builder. I think you want to say , I should make all custom cell programmatically then use inheritance, Am I right ??

Comment: Yeah that's correct. You can't inherit a custom cell build in interface builder and inherit in interface builder again. But you can do that in code... That said, you can inherit your (IB) base cell and than add for example labels in code. (but I don't recommend going that way especially when you want to use autolayout. do it code MUCH easier in this case.)

Comment: Thanks @ Tafh . I have created custom cell in interface builder. I have already created  all custom cell  in interface builder. I have given lot of time to make custom cell in interface builder. Now I don't want to waste time to create it again . So, please let me know any other solution in this case (when custom cell created in interface builder) . Thank in advance .

Comment: You have to link your IB cell to a custom uitableviewcell (code) file, but you probably already did so. Then create IBOutlets of the things you might need to make these new cells possible (you probably need the dimensions and positions of labels images etc) if you use autolayout also add constraints. Then simply create a new file which is a subclass of your base class. Now add your labels, images whatever in this file via code (and in case of autolayout add/update constraints).